# Show that $dL_p(w)=L(w)$, can anyone please give some clue on how to proceed?

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that if $L:R^3\to R^3$ is a linear map and $S\subset R^3$ is a regular surface invariant under $L$, i.e., $L(S)\subset S$, then the restriction $L|S$ is a differentiable map and

$$dL_p(w)=L(w), \text{ }p\in S, w\in T_p(S).$$

My working:
By definition of differential, let $\alpha:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to S$ be a differentiable curve such that $\alpha(0)=p,\text{ }\alpha'(0)=w$. By the chain rule, the curve $\beta=L\circ\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to R^3$ is also differentiable. Then $dL_p(w)=\beta'(0)$. This is as far as I can get.

The thing that bugs me is the condition that $L$ is a linear map, I have little clue about how to use it to show $dL_p(w)=L(w)$. Should we introduce another variable $p'$ and $w'$ to make use of linearity? And also how can use the condition of invariance?

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: You already used the chain rule to show that $\beta$ is differentiable. Why not use it for actual calculation of $\beta'(0)$ ? ;)

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny. But how can I perform the actual calculation of $\beta'(0)$ ? What I can do is just re-writing the calculation, $\beta'(0)=\frac{dL}{d\alpha}\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}$ ? Thanks.

Comment: The chain rule tells you that $D(F\circ G) = DF \circ DG$ :) by $DF$ I mean the Jacobi matrix of mapping $F$. Linear mappings have themselves as their own Jacobi matrix.

Comment: @Evgeny. When you said "linear mappings have themselves as their own Jacobi matrix", are you saying that $dL_p(w)=L(w)$? So we have solved the problem? But we can only write the Jacobian matrix of $dL_p$ in general way for example ($\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}\text{ }$ $\frac{\delta x}{\delta v}$) etc. How can we show that it equals to $L(w)$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Almost. I wanted to say that $DL(x) = L$ for all $x$ and $\beta'(0) = DL(\alpha(0)) \cdot \alpha'(0) =L \cdot w = L(w)$ (this is the chain rule).

Comment: Can I clarify the notation that you are using? Does $DL(x)=L$ mean $dL(x)=L$? Also, why did you not include the $p$? Also, does $DL(\alpha(0)\cdot\alpha'(0))$ mean $dL_p(w)$? Since I am still a beginner, the notation can be confusing to me sometimes. And how can we assume $DL(x)=L$ in the first place, is that what we need to show?

Comment: 1) To me notation $dF$ usually looks like total differential of function, so it's confusing to me. When we have mapping $\mathbf{y} = G(\mathbf{x})$ ($\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, $G(\mathbf{x}) = (G_1(x_1, \dots, x_n), \dots, G_m(x_1, \dots, x_n))$ )by $DG$ I understand the matrix which has element $a_{ij}$ equal to $\frac{\partial G_i}{\partial x_j}$. If you write linear mapping $L$ in coordinates and calculate this derivatives you'll get the same matrix $DL$ for any point. 2) I've included $p$, since $\alpha(0) = p$ :)